# How to implement security in confluent helm charts for kafka

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

I am using confluent helm charts for deploying kafka in kubernetes.
I need to create a secure connection between broker and clients.
How will I achieve this?

Comment: Alternatively,  Confluent offers K8S Operator for it's platform

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently implemented via Helm, and so you'd need to manually mount volumes for certs and add any respective variables for keys and passwords on your own for each Deployment

Ref - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/issues/129